# I want to print the contents of a text file in the filepath. How do I fix it?

Tags: c++

I want to print the text files name and contents of a text file in the filepath. 
i tried change filepath to c:\temp\ but its error
i tried filtered text file this point in if strchr point
i tried to output txt files content in while loop
How do I fix it?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string filepath = "C:\\TEMP\\*.*";              <-  i tried c:\\temp\\ but its error            
    struct _finddata_t fd;
    intptr_t handle;
    if ((handle = _findfirst(filepath.c_str(), &fd)) == -1L)
        printf("file not fount");
    do
    {
        if (strchr(fd.name,'txt')){                     <-  i tried filtered text file this point
            printf("filename : %s \n", fd.name);
            string in_line;             

            ifstream in(filepath + fd.name);              <- i think error this point
            while (getline(in, in_line)) {
                cout << in_line << "\n";          <-i tried to output txt files content this point

            }
            in.close();
        }

    } while (_findnext(handle, &fd) == 0);

    _findclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, strchr() is for looking for a char in a char[] null term string, literal char 'a' must be a single character and is actually int type.  strstr() finds substrings, but your just want .txt at the end of the name, so strcmp( char * + strlen( char*) - 4, ".txt") is better.

Comment: `string filepath = "C:\\TEMP\\*.*";` - That's not a path. That's a glob pattern.

Comment: Might glob for *.txt ?

Comment: Your are generating file names like C:\TEMP\*.*xxx.txt instead of "C:\TEMP\xxx.txt